# Issues trying to connect 2 External Monitors to my Laptop, via 2 Fresco USB to VGA Adapters

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, usb, multiple-monitors, vga

I apologise for this question being rather lengthy my reasoning was, rather than responding to plentiful requests for clarification within the comments section I would instead write my question in detail. So to hopefully make things easier for everyone.

### Overview of Problems:

I've recently purchased 2 Fresco USB to VGA Adapters so I can connect 2 External Monitors to my (ASUS Gaming Powerhouse) Laptop. But I'm experiencing alot of problems trying to get my laptops display to be extended across 3 monitors (2 external monitors and one laptop display). Any help would be very much appreciated :-)

### Link to 2 adapters purchased:

(As I am a new member I can not post more than 2 links, so instead I have below stated the eBay item number which can be searched on eBay to bring up the Fresco USB to VGA Adapter I purchased)

The seller seemed very trust worthy due to their very high eBay rating and great number of sales for this particular item.

- [eBay item number: 301321048723](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-USB-3-0-to-VGA-Video-Graphic-Multi-Display-Cable-Adapter-Card-For-Win-7-8-/301321048723)

### Name of Drivers on the CD accompanying each Fresco USB to VGA Adapter:

FLVGA-2.0.30165.0.exe

*A download link for these drivers can be provided if necessary.*

### Background:

- I am using an Asus Gaming Powerhouse G751JY laptop
- running 64 bit Windows 8.1
- 2 Acer 1600 x 1200 monitors

### F.Y.I:

When each of these monitors are directly connected to my laptop via their individual VGA cables, they each work perfectly without any bugs or issues etc. Prior to attempting to extend my laptop's display over 3 monitors, my laptop operated perfectly without any bugs or issues.

### Problems prior to monitors being detected via USB to VGA cables:

When I first received these cables they were accompanied by a drivers CD, which upon installation resulted in my laptop screen going dark although I could still hear existing sound in the background.

The installation process for these drivers was as follows:

1. I inserted the driver disc into my laptop, then located and executed the driver installation software.
2. I then followed the installation instructions allowing the software to place it's files in a dedicated folder within Program Files in the C drive.
3. Just prior to the installation completing, a command prompt window popped up in response to an element of the installation (I assume this was the case, as no other major programs were running at the time of the installation).
4. Seconds after the command prompt window appeared my laptop screen went dark.

### How I attempted to solve this problem

In which case I first assumed my laptop in response to the installation had attempted to output it's display to a connected monitor (which at the time one wasn't connected). I then attempted using function keys to switch my laptop's choice of display back to my laptop's screen. But this didn't work, instead the screen simply stayed darkened.

I then restarted my computer hoping that upon restart my laptop's display would be as normal. But this also wasn't the case, instead my laptop's screen stayed dark.

Then by selecting F9 on my laptop's keyboard prior and during boot, I then attempted to enter into the Asus Gaming Powerhouse recovery menu and select restart to safe mode. But when the laptop attempted to enter safe mode, the screen returned to a darkened state.

At which point as suggested by the *Recover from boot to blank screens on Windows 10.pdf* document on the Fresco USB to VGA adapter manufacture's website. I then attempted to revert to a restore point via the Asus Gaming Powerhouse recovery menu, but apparently these restore points were corrupted etc. So instead I needed to refresh my system which would uninstall all programs other than those installed via Windows Store and restore PC settings to defaults, as explained in this [link](http://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1008267/). After the system *refresh* was complete, I was able to access my laptop again and view it's output via my laptop's screen.

I then allowed my laptop to complete installing each and every Windows update and restart appropriately. Prior to doing anything else, I then created a restore point.

Once all updates and the restore point was complete. Assuming the above issues were caused by the Fresco USB to VGA drivers being corrupted in some way, I (stupidly) attempted to install the Fresco USB to VGA adapter drivers from another driver disc (this time I attempted those accompanying the second Fresco USB to VGA adapter). Which caused the same issues as discussed above, but on this occasion I was able to successfully restore my laptop to a previous restore point.

At which point I assumed that the drivers accompanying each disc either were not appropriate for my laptop's O.S due to either the version e.g. Windows 8.1 or the bit e.g 64 bit.

So I then visited the support of the website owned by the manufacturer of the USB to VGA adapters and downloaded their *HostDriver_V3.6.8.0.exe* software. But each time I attempted to install it, I received the error message: *fresco logic usb3 host controller is not found*. Even after I followed [suggested instructions like](https://rog.asus.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-34011.html):

*1. Open Windows Power Management or Asus Power4Gear.*

*2. Disable the USB power saving options.*

*3. Proceed to uninstall all those USB devices that are in your picture.*

*4. Reboot.*

*5. Windows will start installing the standard USB drivers upon reboot.*

*6. Download and install USB3_Fresco_Win7_64_Z35240.zip.*

So I then moved onto the other executable on the manufacture's support page *VideoDriver_V2.0.30520.exe* hoping this instead would be the correct and appropriate file. But upon execution and completion of it's installation instructions a familiar command prompt appeared, followed by a similarly darkened screen filling my laptop's display featuring the same issues described above.

So I then:

Utilising Search engines and the search terms:

- *Fresco-Logic USB VGA*
- *fresco logic usb 3.0 to vga "windows 8.1"*
- *fresco usb to vga 3.0*
- etc.

Which eventually led me to a [website](http://www.drivermax.com/driver-download/0/AVCLASS/Fresco+Logic/Fresco+Logic+FL2000+USB+Display+Adapter) which seemed to have up-to-date drivers for Fresco USB to VGA adapter both for my O.S version and bit. After I installed the latest driver for my O.S. both monitors were detected, properly identified and able to be utilised simultaneously as an extended output for my laptop. But although these monitors were now able to be somewhat utilised, further issues began to occur.

### Problems after monitors were finally detected via USB to VGA cables:

After these monitors were detected for a short time everything was fine, but then I began to notice worrying issues as below:

- Firstly every 20 - 30 minutes (rough estimate) one of my monitors (normally the same monitor) became darkened, even though the particular monitor was receiving power as was obvious by the illuminated power light. On each occasion the particular monitor did not display any message to suggest it had been disconnected from my laptop in any way.

I primarily assumed this was due to a screensaver etc. (which was not enabled on my laptop nor did it seem power saving features were enabled on either my laptop or monitors) but after moving the mouse around even in the area of my laptop's display intended to be covered by this monitor; this monitor remained darkened. I then removed and then between 5 - 10 seconds after (rough estimate) reconnected the USB to VGA cable for this monitor, after which the region of my laptop's display intended to be covered by this monitor was again outputted correctly to this monitor. This problem continues to occur, which is rather annoying.

- Secondly every hour or so (rough estimate) both external monitors will become darkened and my laptop will in turn freeze, suddenly not responding to any key presses etc. forcing me to restart my laptop so I can use it again. This problem also continues to occur, which is rather worrying.

### How I attempted to solve this problem

- In regard to the first issue (one monitor going dark every 20 - 30 mins) I removed the ASUS utility USB charger plus (as it was suggested this could be the culprit, as it was only allowing so much power to connected devices) and then restarted my laptop. But this had no effect and the problem still remains.
- In regard to the second issue (both monitors going dark and then a full laptop crash not responding to any input) the only temporary solution I found to allow my laptop to be usable over long durations was to disconnect both USB to VGA adapters which would allow my laptop to respond normally. But this does not really solve the problem.

### Further information in regard to the above

(In response to comments)

When these issues occur both adapters are connected and due to the large duration between crashes and necessity of sustained use, I haven't been able to test with a single adapter connected.

Also I have attempted to install a great number of drivers as above and those most recently described (FLUSBVGA-1.1.315.0) seem to be closest to working (although the above described issues still exist).

Earlier iterations of the *FLUSBVGA* or closest working-ish drivers, seem to have the darkened screen issue or system crash and forced restart upon completion of their installation. I haven't yet been able to find any other available drivers to test, as a means to possibly solve the above issues.

In regard to testing upon other systems as these issues (number of system crashes and their possible impact upon hardware etc.) are rather worrying (at least to me) I would rather not put another machine at risk.

This is as far as I have got, any help in solving these issues would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I have no solution. Just two things you could test:
1) Does it freeze with only one adapter (possibility of badly written drivers).
2) If you got a spare disk you could try if it also freezes on another OS.

Comment: As my response is a little lengthy, I will post it in the above Further Information Section

Answer (score 0):

Try different inputs. Surely one of the Monitors has a dvi / HDMI/ or displayport input.  My old Lenovo t420 has a displayport and VGA . I'm running 5 monitors of this laptop including 1 lg 29 inch  ultra wide 2560 res with only HDMI input and a 27 inch crossover 2560 res as well with only a dual dvi d active input. 2 dell 22 1440 inch running VGA and my 32 samsung TV using HDMI input.
Best to have plug and play adapters. I had problems running one adapter because different software was recognized and a Taurus  mini hub which included a HDMI 2 and a VGA output wouldn't let the USB to VGA run .  In your case sounds like u need different hardware adapter( preferably plug an play) so both r recognized and run properly

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: Can you edit out some of the extraneous information in your answer that doesn't address the question? It makes your post appear to not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

This adapter is a simple ADC, not a graphic card. The image is created in computer's memory, and streamed through USB 3, using a lot of bandwidth.

Chance is that you have connected both adapters to the same USB hub, so there's a bottleneck. Have you tried connecting one?